# Searching and Removing pointers from vectors/lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector

I have two classes, let's call the first one Car and the other one ShowRoom.

What I want to do is to create either a vector or a list in which I will store pointers to Car objects. Then, I want to search these vectors/lists for a specific pointer (that will be passed as a parameter to a function called removeCar() ) and then delete that object along with its pointer from the vector/list.

I have been trying to implement this idea for quite a while now using the algorithm functions "find" and "remove", but I keep on getting errors on object conversion. I try to dereference the pointer but then I get an error on how I'm giving too many arguments to "remove".

Here is the code implemented in ShowRoom function Delete:

```
list <Car*> inventory;

void Delete(Car* BMW)
{
    if (find(inventory.begin(),inventory.end(),BMW) != inventory.end())
        remove(inventory.begin(),inventory.end(),BMW);
    else 
       cout << "Car not found" << endl;
}
```

Help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have nearly answered it yourself, just create a vector , for example: `std::vector<Cars> cars;`, then just do `cars.push_back(*pointer_to_Cars_object);`. That would allow you to have a vector of Cars objects; Pointers point to the object, so in theory, they are really just the address of the Cars objects. From there to iterate through the list would just be: `for(auto it  = cars.begin(); it != cars.end(); it++)`. This would allow you to iterate through the list.The `for` body would be where you perform your algorithm.

Comment: 1. include `<algorithm>`, 2. use `std::list::remove` instead of `std::remove`

Comment: Try `inventory.remove(BMW);`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki : When I say std::list::remove(inventory1.begin(),inventory1.end(),BMW);, it tells me  " argument list for class template "std::list" is missing " .

Comment: @Ghostlysunny I didn't mean `std::list::remove()`, I meant `inventory.remove(BMW);` (member function `std::list<T>::remove`), and I guess adding `<algorithm>` helps with `find`, doesn't it?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki : I forgot to add <algorithm>, so thanks for pointing that out :) . Also I still keep on getting these two errors: " IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Car*>>>" to "Car *const" exists" 
and
"IntelliSense: too many arguments in function call"

I am not sure if Visual Studio is being difficult about this, should I try and compile in Linux?

Comment: @Ghostlysunny posting actual code with a full error message would suffice

Comment: @Ghostlysunny from the error message I can tell you are not dereferencing an iterator somewhere where you should, but noone will help you on the basis of a short error message hidden in a comment. Are you trying to pass an iterator to `remove()` instead of `BMW` (because it smells so) ?

Comment: Please include the full error messages, with the line they reference, inside the question (you can edit it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is always problematical to store ordinary pointers in STL containers.  The STL is deigned to store objects, not pointers.  Storing pointers means that you and the STL are getting in each other's way as you both try to call copy constructors and destructors.

This is the kind of situation that shared pointers were invented for, they make life so much easier.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

I would also advise NOT using a pointer to identify your cars.  It is much more reliable ( less bugs ) to provide each car object with a unique ID and use that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    // Construct a Car, assigning it a unique ID
    Car()
    {
        myID = lastID++;
    }
    // Cars are equivalent if they have the same ID
    bool operator==( const Car& other ) const
    {
        return myID == other.myID;
    }
    // Sort cars by ID
    bool operator<( const Car& other ) const
    {
        return myID < other.myID;
    }
    // access the IF
    int getID() { return myID; }
private:
    int myID;
    static int lastID;
};

int Car::lastID = 0;

typedef std::shared_ptr< Car > car_t;
std::set< car_t> Inventory;

void Delete( car_t BMW)
{
    Inventory.erase( BMW );
}

int main()
{
    car_t car0( new Car );
    car_t car1( new Car );
    car_t car2( new Car );
    Inventory.insert( car0 );
    Inventory.insert( car1 );
    Inventory.insert( car2 );

    cout << "Current Inventory: ";
    for( auto c : Inventory )
    {
        cout << c->getID() << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    Delete( car1 );

    cout << "Current Inventory: ";
    for( auto c : Inventory )
    {
        cout << c->getID() << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As a further optimization, I use the std::set container for your inventory.  This will enforce that every car in the inventory is unique and greatly speed finds in large inventories.

Comment: Besides resource management, why else would you use `std::unique_ptr `and `std::shared_ptr`?I do prefer unique_ptr/shared_ptr in most cases over a regular pointer just because it will delete() once it goes out of scope.

Comment: Because it will only delete the object if every pointer to the object is deleted - thus preventing many common bugs.  Also, the STL is designed to use objects rather than pointers, and a shared pointers looks like an object to the STL, again preventing many kinds of numerous bugs, especially to do with unintended executions of copy constructors.

Comment: ahh ok thank you. I'm halfway through Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ Programming language , learning useful things everyday; I'm still a noob.

Comment: `shared_ptr` should be avoided most of the times, and chances are that if you think that a particular case warrants it, it does not. The problem of `shared_ptr` is not only the risk of memory leaks (which is real enough), it's also that it screws up copy semantics, which can lead to bewildering bugs.

Comment: I disagree.  In my experience shared_ptr sorts out large numbers of bugs, especially when using STL containers.

Comment: I got the basic gist of it, thanks for the code to explain :)